# Error in deploy.sh file during ci cd in azure VM

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment, azure-virtual-machine

I am using a pipeline for azure devops to ci cd azure VM, but this error occurs on the CD,
So, even if I put the deploy.sh file according to the path, an error pops up saying that the path cannot be created and help me.
[image]

The yaml file is organized like this

[image]

Comment: Hi @crispy, the yaml pipeline you shared is build pipeline and the result you shared is release pipeline. You need share the release definition here. In addition, please check the release pipeline source, if you are using build Artifact, you need add the deploy.sh file to build Artifact. Please try it and kindly share the result here.

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: no thank you i fixed